# detecting increased partition in vmware without restarting guest OS

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-vsphere, disk-space-utilization

we're running a non-critical production ubuntu server, and i need to increase the partition size from 17GB to 30GB without restarting the guest OS.

On my VSPHERE, i increased the storage size on my ubuntu guest OS and added 30 more GB. 
Tutorials keep saying to run command:

`echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan` which returns no results on my end.

ive tried `host0, host1, host2` which displays no result as well.

no use for `gparted` since this server is pure CLI based.

im a little rusty in linux, since i am more used to windows.
i need to carefully increase the capacity without affecting any services running on it.

Answer (score 1):

Check that there is actually a file `/sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan`, and that there isn't one with, say, `host3`.  Additionally, if you have configured the server to use a virtual IDE disk instead of a SCSI one I don't believe this will work, and you may be doomed to reboot it.

If there are more than 3 SCSI hosts, you could try issuing this on all of them, but that would be a very odd configuration for a VM.

Comment: i see. thats very unfortunate. moving forward, how would I configure my future deployments of VM's that does this 'no-reset-needed'. what should i research about? thanks.

Comment: It should be sufficient to ensure that the OS supports host rescanning and that the virtual disks are defined as SCSI devices.